# Spivak Calculus : I.1-18c - Schwarz inequality proof

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Spivak Calculus (World Student Series, 1e, 1967):
Part I, Chapter 1, Problem 18 c):

> Prove the Schwartz inequality by using $2xy \le x^2 + y^2$ (how is this derived?) with
>
> $$
> x = \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}, \qquad y = \frac{y_i}{\sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}}, 
> $$
>   first for $i = 1$ and then for $i = 2$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563246/172142) is the solution taken from the answer book.

I gave it myself a try and came up with the following lengthier version:

Assume the Schwarz inequality not to hold:

$$
(\exists x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}) \; 0 \le \sqrt{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2)} < x_1y_1 + x_2y_2.
$$

Then

$$
(x_1^2 + x_2^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2) < (x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2.
$$

After some reformulations:

$$
x_1^2(y_1^2 + y_2^2) + y_1^2(x_1^2 + x_2^2) < 2x_1y_1(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)
$$

Introducing

$x := \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}, \qquad y := \frac{y_1}{\sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}}$,

I'm ending up with

$$
x^2 + y^2 < 2xy \underbrace{\frac{x_1y_1 + x_2y_2}{\sqrt{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2)}}}_{>1}.
$$

Since this inequality holds, e.g. for $x = y = 1$, the assumption holds for certain values of $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$.

Which causes the proof-by-contradiction to fail. Can you see why?

Comment: It is Schwarz,  not "Schwartz".

Comment: To see that $2xy \leq x^2+y^2$, notice that $$ (x-y)^2 \geq 0 \iff x^2-2xy+y^2\geq 0 \iff 2xy \leq x^2+y^2. $$

Comment: @Sobi: Agreed. But my point is that the assumption leads to the statement $x^2 + y^2 < \alpha xy$, where $\alpha > 2$.